# High train accuracy poor test accuracy

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have a neural network which classify 3 output.My dataset is very small, I have 340 images for train, and 60 images for test. I build a model and when I compile at my result is this:

Epoch 97/100
306/306 [==============================] - 46s 151ms/step - loss: 0.2453 - accuracy: 0.8824 - val_loss: 0.3557 - val_accuracy: 0.8922
Epoch 98/100
306/306 [==============================] - 47s 152ms/step - loss: 0.2096 - accuracy: 0.9031 - val_loss: 0.3795 - val_accuracy: 0.8824
Epoch 99/100
306/306 [==============================] - 47s 153ms/step - loss: 0.2885 - accuracy: 0.8627 - val_loss: 0.4501 - val_accuracy: 0.7745
Epoch 100/100
306/306 [==============================] - 46s 152ms/step - loss: 0.1998 - accuracy: 0.9150 - val_loss: 0.4586 - val_accuracy: 0.8627

when I predict the test images, test accuracy is poor.
What should I do ? I also use ImageDatagenerator for data augmentation  but the result is same.Is it because I have small dataset.

Comment: Did you shuffle the data before splitting into training and validation to make sure the validation data is somewhat representative of the data-set you are training on?

Comment: I have 3 classes and what I did for splitting is this:
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,random_state=15,test_size=0.10)
How can I shuffle the data ?
Thank you.

Comment: try use `Dropout` layer on your fully connected layer, it will help reduce your overfit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already used Dropout layer,but I used it like this:
Conv-Max-Dropout
Conv-Max-Dropout
...
Flatten
Dense
Dropout
Dense
Dropout
Dense
Should I use Dropout layer only after FC layer ?

Comment: can you share the model architecture?

Comment: I shared it below

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regularization on fully connected layers. But the fact that you already have high validation accuracy it's probably your data. your train data might not fully represent your test data. try to analyze that and make sure you do all the pre processing on the test data before testing as you did for the train data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will use regularization on FC layers. But I didn't understand this part in your answer: " make sure you do all the pre processing on the test data".Shouldn't I use my test data as raw images ? Should I use Image Data generator on test data ?

Comment: I mean if you are for example normalizing the images before training or subtracting the mean etc, do the same thing on the test data too.